# Unable to consume Kafka messages using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am unable to consume Kafka messages running in a local mode using Apache camel. I am not viewing any Kafka consumer properties when application starts. Below is my Kafka consumer code

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public final class MessageConsumerClient {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageConsumerClient.class);

    private MessageConsumerClient() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        LOG.info("About to run Kafka-camel integration...");

        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

        // Add route to send messages to Kafka

        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                PropertiesComponent pc = getContext().getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
                pc.setLocation("classpath:application.properties");

                log.info("About to start route: Kafka Server -> Log ");

                from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"
                        + "&maxPollRecords={{consumer.maxPollRecords}}" + "&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}"
                        + "&seekTo={{consumer.seekTo}}" + "&groupId={{consumer.group}}").routeId("FromKafka")
                                .log("${body}");
            }
        });
        camelContext.start();

        Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);

        camelContext.stop();
    }

}
```

I am using the following dependencies in pom.xml:

1.Camel core - 2.21.1
2.Camel Kafka - 2.21.1

### Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any help would be much appreciated since I am not able to view any logs when executed.

Comment: What logging library are you using? Do you have a correct file for it? log4j.properties or logback.xml, for example? If you see no logs, Kafka isn't the problem

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using slf4j library

Comment: That's not the actual library. It's an adapter for other logging libraries. Please add your pom.xml, or other build tool file, to the question

Comment: @cricket_007: Updated pom.xml

Comment: It can help to take a look at the Camel Kafka Example, and see if you can get that working and compare what you do (wrong): https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples